# How to Export an Excel file (.xlsx) format using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-job

Actually i looking to export an excel(.xlsx) file format. Below is my query which is used to send .csv file format using **sp_send_dbmail**

```
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'eMail Notification',
@recipients = 'abc@gmail.com',  
@query = 'use [dbname] select im.FullName as EmployeeName, im.MemberIC as NRIC 
         from tblIndividualMst im           
         where im.RecStatus = ''A''
         and (im.DateOfResign >= getdate() or im.DateOfResign is null)' ,
@subject = 'Test',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ,
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv',
@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =32767,
@query_result_no_padding=1;
```

So while i tried to modifiy the file format from "test.csv" to "test.xlsx", all the data's messing up in test.xlsx. So how can i modify my query to get correct .xlsx file format.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have once tried it earlier. You can use this, though this might not work with sp_send_dbmail :

```
insert into OPENROWSET(
   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\testfile.xls;;HDR=YES', 
   'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select * from table1
```

Alternatively, I will suggest to use SSIS which is actually built to do ETL related task. You can write from any source to excel destination and use send mail task for sending it. It is configurable to be used with SQL Server Agent as well.

SSIS details :

- [Microsoft link of SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services)
- [Email excel file using SSIS](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-email-flat-file-or-excel.html)
- [Email files using SSIS](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/88305/creating-and-attaching-excel-file-as-attachment-in.html)

Comment: After doing this you should be able to use `@file_attachments='d:\testfile.xls'` on sp_send_dbmail to send the file